# Using functions in R

Tags: r, function, matrix, sapply

I am trying to use functions to do some arithmetic on a matrix and stuck.

HEre is the function:

```
tweet.score = function(tweets)
{
  #browser()
   tweets[,3]<- ifelse(as.numeric(tweets[,1])- as.numeric(tweets[,2]) >= 10,2,1)
  return(tweets)
}

sapply(bush1,tweet.score)
```

Here bush1 has 3 columns and I am using column 1 and column 2 (converting to numbers) and saving in the third column

When I run this line outside of the function, it works perfectly.. but when I use Sapply, it fails.. says "incorrect number of dimensions"

Comment: If you apply `sapply` to a matrix it applies the function to every element of the matrix. But your function expects a matrix

Comment: What are you trying to do with `sapply`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sapply` is not needed

```
bush1<-tweet.score(bush1)
```

Should work